# Javascript how to convert Json array values into string using join

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string as output from a function.

`{"0":{"error":"ERROR_SPECIAL_CHAR","message":"Missing a special character"},"1":{"error":"ERROR_CHAR_UPPERCASE","message":"Must contain at least one uppercase letter"}`

I want to get the output in the format.
`"Missing a special character, Must contain at least one uppercase letter"`

I tried `Array.isArray(err)? err.join(',')`, but I get the output
`[object Object],[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically access the individual properties then join them. However since there might be a few of them, we need a little loop.

```js
var obj = {
  "0": {
    "error": "ERROR_SPECIAL_CHAR",
    "message": "Missing a special character"
  },
  "1": {
    "error": "ERROR_CHAR_UPPERCASE",
    "message": "Must contain at least one uppercase letter"
  }
}

var messages = []
for (var key in obj) {
  messages.push(obj[key].message)
}
var str = messages.join(", ");
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Would probably be a good idea if you made this a bit more dynamic - I don't suppose there's always going to be exactly two errors, but the number will likely vary.

Comment: Correct I'll fix thanks